# Mediawiki create user error after migration

Tags: windows, debian, migration, debian-squeeze, mediawiki

So I had a mediawiki installed on windows with MySQL (running on AWS RDS). I've since moved it to a debian server for various reasons, but I think I've messed up the database because of the different versions of mediawiki I have used.

The windows install was v 1.20alpha (58f390e).
The new debian install is v 1.15.5-2squeeze4.

I've tried to update debian but it doesn't find an update, so is this the latest squeeze version?

Everything seems to work ok except adding users. It gives me a database error so I ran `php maintenance/update.php` which ran some stuff OK but didn't make a difference. I think I've not done the correct approach to this sort of move, does anyone know of a better way of doing it? I still have the old wiki running - but not used - on windows (using the same database) so I could always try this again.

Comment: I don't really see how this is off topic.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The simple fact is almost no web-apps are design to handle a down-grade.  Once a database has been updated, you usually can never go to an older version without causing problems.

I don't know much specifics about mediwiki, but my guess is that you have two choices.

- Remove the packaged version of mediawiki you found on your Debian system, and you need to manually re-install, using the same version or newer version then what you were running.
- Or simply, or not so simply, manually migrate/rebuild the entire site on the older version.

Comment: I think the best thing then is to wait for the debian version to be upgraded or to rebuild the whole thing.

Comment: Waiting for the Debian package is probably a bad idea.  Since it won't be updated until wheezy is released next year.

Comment: I ended up rebuilding the database. I've learnt not to switch os's with this kinda software!